# Python - Ordenação de lista sem o sort()

Tags: python, lista, classificação, break

Eu estava estudando esse código de ordenação de lista e tem algumas coisas que eu não entendi:

- Por que é necessário o `break`?
- Por que deixar o `else` identado com o `if` e sem o `break` não funciona?
- Por que com o `break` o `else` fica identado 4 espaços para trás do `if`?
- Ao colocar o `break` 4 espaços para trás, o código entra no `else` na primeira vez e depois não entra mais. Por que?

```
lista = [11, 11, 15, 12, 13, 9, 4, 1, 2, 1, 11, 15, 41, 42, 40]
ordenado = []

for numero in lista:
    for chave, valor in enumerate(ordenado):
        if numero < valor:
            ordenado.insert(chave, numero)
            break
    else:
        ordenado.append(numero)
        
print(ordenado)
```

Comment: Pra ajudar com um ponto, em Python um `for` pode ter um `else` associado a ele. Basicamente, se o loop não for interrompido por um `break`, ele entra no `else`, veja a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse codigo pegar os valores de `lista`  e vai colocando em `ordenado`. Na primeira iteração do `for` `ordenado` está vazio entao, a instrucao salta para o `else` e adicionar o valor 11 em `ordenado`. Na segunda iteração a instruçao ja entra no segundo `for` e compara `if numero < valor`, e apenas compara com o 11 pois este é o unico elemento de ordenado até o momento, entao o outro 11 e adicionado a `ordenado` dentro bloco `else`. Na terceira iteração ocorre o mesmo que a segunda e 15 é adicionado ao `ordenado`. Na quarta iteração `numero = 12`, o segundo `for` compara `if numero < valor` `numero=12` com (11,11,15), quando chega na comparação `12 < 15` a instrucao entra no `if` e insere o 12 na 2ª posição, antes ocupada pelo 15 que agora passará a ocupar a 3ª. Na 4ª iteração,observe que `numero` = 12 e este foi trocado com o 15 no `if`, isso quer dizer que `ordenado = [11,11,12,15]`, poi o 15 foi empurrado para a posicao seguinte, a lista `ordenado`   que tinha 3 valores (11,11,15) agora tem 4, entao se nao encontrar um break haverá uma nova comparacao `12 < 15`, entao ocorre outra troca, agora temos outro 12 na 4ª posicao e o 15 é empurrado novamente para a 5ª. Novamente `ordenado` aumentou mais um elemento entao, entao ociclo anterior repete infintamente.

1 - Impede que as troca se repitam para o mesmo valor 12 e 15 de exemplo como dito antes.

2 - O `else` esta identado com o segundo for de modo que é executado todas as vezes, é onde os valores de lista sao adcionados a `ordenado` e o break impede o loop , repetindo o de antes, se fosse identado com o if ou o numero era trocado ou era adionado no final lista, isso impediria que todos da `lista` fossem adiocnados em `ordenado`.

3 - Por que precisa ser executado todas as vezes, nesse exemplo, 15 vezes para adionar todos os valores de `lista` em `ordenado`

4 - Nesse caso o else ficaria fora do loop entao é executado somente uma vez e no final da execucao.